# optional execution path with combine

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I'm new to Combine Swift for iOS and am struggling with an error about types.

I have a case to save users and optionally save roles if they are provided.

In either case, whether roles were provided or not I have to return the `userId` of the new record. Please guide me to fix the error.

I have used `Just(userId)` to take care of the case if roles are not provided, and it turns out to be the problem.

```
func save(_ user: User, roles: [Role]?) -> AnyPublisher<Int?, Error> {

    return repository.save(user)
            .flatMap { [weak self] userId -> AnyPublisher<Int?, Error> in

                if let roles = roles {
                    return repository.updateByUserId(userId, roles: roles)
                            .map { _ in userId } // return userId
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    return Just(userId).eraseToAnyPublisher() // error - return userId
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

> > Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<Int?, Never>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<Int?, any Error>'

Comment: A common issue with Just in a `flatMap`; thoroughly discussed in https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is related to the error types. When using `Just(userId)`, it returns a publisher with a completion of `Never`. However, your function is declared to return a `Publisher` with an error of type Error. To fix this, you need to introduce an error using the `setFailureType` operator on `Just(userId)`.

```
func save(_ user: User, roles: [Role]?) -> AnyPublisher<Int?, Error> {
    return repository.save(user)
        .flatMap { [weak self] userId -> AnyPublisher<Int?, Error> in
            if let roles = roles {
                return repository.updateByUserId(userId, roles: roles)
                    .map { _ in userId }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
                return Just(userId)
                    .setFailureType(to: Error.self) // Introduce an error type
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

By using `setFailureType(to: Error.self)`, you are effectively making `Just(userId)` conform to the expected error type, allowing it to fit into the `AnyPublisher<Int?, Error>` type.